# Apache to limit number of different IP addresses that can connect to a server

Tags: apache, ip

Me and a group of friends are developing a server that we want to have a limited number of users accessing to it. We first tried the KeepAlive and MaxClients directives with a relative small timeout. It worked fine in an experimental simple webpage.

But our webpage only loads a portion of it. I think it's because we use the AJAX model that does multiple connections. One per one part of the web interface.

Anyway to overcome this we though of blocking by number of different IP's connected and not different connections. We tried to find an Apache module/directive that does this but we keep finding modules that limit bandwidth/connections per IP (which is the reverse thing of what we keep trying to find).

Does anyone know something that can help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of things are usually done in routing since that's where you want to handle DOS related issues. There is however mod_evasive, and you can find it by Googling. It is not really maintained anymore and doesn't seem to have official homepage either but if you insist using Apache for that sort of stuff I would check it out in any case...